# Non-trivial functional depencency in the closure of set of functional dependency

Tags: relational-database, functional-dependencies

`enter code here`I am Preparing for my database exam.

I have a question about finding the non-trivial functional dependency for R={A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
 with the given set of functional dependencies as:

```
A->B
A->D
C->EA
F->G
```

The candidiate key in this case is CF since CF+=ABCDEFG

A non-trivial functional dependency could be C->B

Is this true?If not how to calculate non-trivial functional dependency and how to prove it using Armstrong Axioms

Thank you for your patience and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

`C->EA`

is equivalent to

`C->E` and `C->A`

Comment: Oh okay,got it. 

C->B can be obtained by
C->EA which by decomposition rule can be C->E and C->A
A->B
By Transitivity, C->B which is a non-trivial functional dependency 
Am I correct?